# What is the classification of the undead from Pirates of the Caribbean?

Tags: terminology, undead, pirates-of-the-caribbean

They're not exactly zombies or ghosts. They're spectral beings in moonlight but have physical form othertimes. How would this be classified?

Comment: i'm pretty sure they're just "cursed".

Comment: I'm not satisfied with that. Lots of things are cursed. I feel there should be other definitions that can be applied here.

Comment: good thing i didn't post it as an answer then

Comment: Classified based upon which scale?

Comment: [Sir](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087332/quotes), what you have there is what we refer to as a focused, non-terminal, repeating phantasm, or a Class Five full roaming vapor. Real nasty one, too!

Comment: but they're not vapors. They have skeletal and corporeal forms.

Comment: @CookieOfFortune: It was not an entirely serious comment, as the link at the beginning may indicate. Perhaps you should consult [Tobin's Spirit Guide](http://ghostbusters.wikia.com/wiki/Tobin's_Spirit_Guide). :-)

Comment: Why do we think they belong to any 'category'?

Comment: @CookieOfFortune Believe me, phantom42 knows his stuff where PotC is concerned - he actually appeared in it!

Comment: If you're looking for what they'd be in D&D terms... Possibly Karrnathi Skeletons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [transcript](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Pirates-of-the-Caribbean.html) only refers to them as skeletons.

The *Pirates of the Caribbean* [wiki](http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Cursed_crew) refers to them as "Cursed."

If neither of these suit you, then I would say simply "the undead" would be the best term, based on what Barbosa says:

> We are not among the living and so we cannot die...but neither are we dead! We have all the desires of the living, but cannot satisfy them!